# Is it better to define images in direct html or css?

Tags: html, css, image

If I have the choice to insert images directly into the html or in the css, say for example a link wrapped in an image I could do either...

```
<a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" width="" height="" /></a>
```

Or I could do...

```
<a id="img" href="#"></a>

#img {background: url('#') no-repeat; height: #; width: #;}
```

Which is better and why? Both work as wanted but is there any difference to load times etc, or any considered better practice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using images in HTML is better when the image has any contextual meaning... if it is a decorative picture without any contextual meaning, then use CSS. CSS is for presentation, HTML is for content.

**The best hint for you to determine whether to use HTML or CSS for a picture is:**
If I remove the picture, will the web-page content still make sense?

An image in HTML is meant to provide a visual meaning in context, with a meaningful text fall-back. Using an A element without any content should be avoided since its content will have a relationship with the link, for browsers and web-crawlers (such a Google bot).

Use CSS images **only** for decorative purposes. Otherwise it can damage your search engine rankings. Always provide an **alt** attribute for images, determine what will it be imagining that an eventual visitor cannot see any images.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Better yet, what are Google's Views? They can detect and do penalize for hidden text these days: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66353

Comment: @Doozer Right, nowadays those hacks better be avoided. If it is not useful for the user, don’t do it.

Comment: Not always.  See this response from Matt Cutts of Google: http://www.threadwatch.org/node/4313#comment-26923.  Oatmeal of SEOmoz also recommends it: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/css-image-replacements-and-seo

Answer (score 4):

If the image has context, such as a logo, or a photo, I would suggest loading it as an `<img>` Make sure you are providing alt text for accessibility and SEO reasons as well.

If an image has no context in the scope of the page, then I think the correct place for it, is defined the in the CSS which controls the design.

The whole idea is to separate your presentation from your content as much as you can. An Image can be content, and if so, should be in it.

Comment: I agree, in other words if the image is content use img, if the image is part of the layout/graphic design of the site use css.

Comment: @stivlo added a line in regarding the image as content, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I try to put as many images in CSS as possible but Doozer and Mario have good points. If the image is important to the context, it can go in the HTML. I will also use `<img>` tags when text needs to float around and image.

One thing that CSS can do that `<img>` can't are [CSS image sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites). This is the only real performance benefit that you'll get from one or the other. Performance-hungry websites like youtube.com will combine many images into one large composite image in order to cut down on the HTTP traffic (and therefore the page load times). For example, this is a sprite taken from youtube.com.

[image]

Comment: Sprites is definitely one area they don't work, you're right. Typically sprites are design focused, so they really belong in the CSS anyhow.

Comment: @DoozerBlake That's true. I can't recall ever seeing sprites used for photo galleries or the picture at the start of an article, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Follow principles of semantic HTML.  If the image is content, ie a thumbnail, photo, or button, use an `<img>` element.  If it is more a part of the page design, a background image may be more appropriate.

A more specific example:  If you are using your image as an icon next to a text link, use a background-image:

[image: Print icon with text]

```
<span class="printIcon" onclick="window.print()">Print</a>

.printIcon { background: url(...) no-repeat; padding-left: 20px }
```

If your image is the button itself, with no text aspect, use an `<img>` element with an appropriate alt attribute that would work to substitue for the image if it is unavailable.

[image: print button]

```
<img src="printButton.png" alt="Print" onclick="window.print()" />
```